# How to prevent users modifying foreign keys in queries?

Tags: sql, sqlite, authentication

I have tables with foreign key relationships:

```
Users:
id,
has_many posts

Posts:
id,
has_many paragraphs

Paragraph:
id,
String text
```

I have queries to view a post by post's id and view a paragraph by a paragraph's id. My schema is more complicated than this, but there's still clear ownership of resources by a user with specific id. Given the id of a user, is there any way in SQL to validate queries can only be done for resources owned by that user?

```
validateUserForPostId(postID, userID):
IF CreateSQLQuery("SELECT parent.ID FROM posts child JOIN on users on parent.ID = child.userID WHERE child.ID = ?", postID) == userID:
return true; // Valid, so we should be able to read or write post with ID = postID
```

```
validateUserForParagraphId(paragraphID):
// Similar join logic
```

Schema can get complicated and become annoying to write. Is there a built in SQL solution to this? I'm using SQLite but a general solution also works.

Comment: How do you know what query comes from which user? Sqlite has no user/login/permissions whatsoever.

Comment: In this situation, we will use Oauth and the email used for Oauth is stored in the User  table.

Comment: And that gives the user SQL access to the database or will you be in control of the queries being executed?
Because if there's always a relation between the data and the user record you could just supply the user ID in the where clause of the query right?

Comment: The user will never have direct access to the database, we have a server that interacts with the database.  But the user could modify the API requests to request resources they shouldn't have access to.  We can, as you said, use a WHERE clause to supply the user ID, but this has to be done with multiple JOINs in some instances and with different JOINs depending on the resource requested.  This just seems annoying to maintain.

Comment: You might want to use a ORM to deal with data-structure complexity. I love SQLAlchemy (Python), but any can help you with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering we need to be clear about one thing: `sqllite` here (or any other potential database engine) is not aware that the data inside your tables is users, ownership and so on. These are bytes, and bytes only, from the perspective of your DB engine.

If you’re trying to solve that problem on the DB Engine side, the only way is to `JOIN` to the ownership tables on every query and filter out the data. For example, if you’re trying to read a post, instead of doing:

```
select
    content, timestamp, userID
from
    posts
```

you’d need to pass in a parameter with current user ID into the query to minimize checks:

```
select
    posts.content,
    posts.timestamp,
    posts.userID
from
    posts child
    join users on parent.ID = child.userID
where
    parent.ID = '?'
    and child.ID = '?'
```

A popular solution for making it slightly more manageable is using things like Stored Procedures (a lot database engines support them). It becomes something like:

```
EXEC sp_getPost “postID”, “userID”
```

Another approach would be creating views on the database engine side that perform neccessary joins and always expose a consistent column name (like `authorUserId`) to filter on.

However, for large modern applications or services it’s common to address it on the application code, and not on the DB side.

Comment: The solution of doing joins is what I was trying to describe in the question, but it seems wild to rewrite joins for every SQL query done.  If this is the only way though, I guess I will do it.  That stored procedure thing does seem helpful though, or maybe I can write functions that do this validation before doing any reads or writes.

Comment: By the way, how can this possibly be handled on the Application side?  If a client sends an API request to your backend, the only way we would be able to check that the username/user email/user ID the client is authorized (through oauth or whatever) as is associated with a given post is by checking the database to make sure that user created the given post.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, the idea behind handling it on the application side is you always read both pieces of data from the database and just do not return results back. Various app frameworks/middlewares to make it more automatable/flexible (for example, force the app to check every output, no matter the endpoint, look for a set of common fields (like owner ID), compare it to some context value and modify the response if necessary prior to returning. So you always read, always return and just make sure that there’s a field present in the output. Your result gets intercepted, inspected, and adjusted

Comment: And, to be fair, there are very specific things that are designed to "magically" solve this problem.

For example, if you hapenned to be using .NET/.NET Core for the API, and SQL Server for your DB, and Active Directory/Integrated authentication, and configered Row-Level Security in SQL Server... then you could completely forget about it, and just query the DB.

But it's not realistic in most of the cases.

Comment: Just realized, regarding "rewriting joins" concern. You can write those joins once by creating views on the DB side, and querying views instead.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you!  Regarding the "views", to avoid "rewriting joins", why don't we just write functions that validation whether a given postID or paragraphId is associated with a userId before doing subsequent SQL queries?  Is the purpose of the views to cache the associations between these IDs so that these "validation SQL join queries" do not add much additional latency?